# Problem removing event while dialog closed(React useEffect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add 'key-down' event while my dialog is open but somehow my event still triggered even when the dialog closed.

I wrapped up the event handling function in order to work fine in useEffect hook.

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect} from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default function FormDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    document.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeyEventHandler);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyEventHandler);
    }
},[]);


  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };



  const handleKeyEventHandler = useCallback((e) => {
    if(e.keyCode===13 && e.ctrlKey) {
        //my event
        alert('event triggered')
    }
  }, []);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
            occasionally.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="Email Address"
            type="email"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Subscribe
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Did I remove event incorrectly? Please let me know what should I've done to fix this...

Comment: Have you tried it without wrapping the `handleKeyEventHandler` with `useCallback`?

Comment: @mddg Yes. It's still triggering while dialog closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, what happens is that your component is not unmounting, and, therefore, the event is not triggered. The unsubscribe function of the `useEffect` would be called if the component `FormDialog` was unmounted, not the `Dialog`, which is the behaviour you want.

Instead, you could use the `useEffect` to listen for changes on the `open` variable, which toggles the `Dialog`, and do:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
        // In this case, set the event listener
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyEventHandler);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, remove the event listener
        document.removeEventListener('keydown',handleKeyEventHandler);
    }
}, [open]);
```

That would probably work. However, it is a bit overengineered. What I would do, instead, would be to reuse the `handleClose` and `handleOpen` functions to set or remove the event listener:

```
const handleOnOpen = () => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyEventHandler);
    setOpen(true);
}

const handleOnOpen = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyEventHandler);
    setOpen(false);
}
```